# Wordpress Download Document

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a question. I was searching for a solution for hours, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a website (wordpress --> contact form 7). I have a litte plugin that gets the a url var.

www.mysite.com/contactform?**var=1**

The user fill out the form and push the button OK.

Then I have a redirection: www.mysite.com/thanks?**var=1** (an other contact form 7 page)

On this site, I would like to give the user the possibility to download a document. I have e.g. document A, document B, document C in my webfolder. Doc A belongs to var=1, B to var=2 and doc C to var=3.

So, when the URL is www.mysite.com/thanks?**var=2**, the user can only download the document B. My problem is: I don't like to create a single page for each document/variable. Is there a possibility to change the hyperlink inside of a page dependent on the URL var?

I hope you understand me. Please excuse my english.

Greets, Yanick

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable is set, and return the desired url based on its value:

```
$url = '';

if( isset( $_GET['var'] ) ) :

    if( '1' == $_GET['var'] )
        $url = 'http://example.com/downloads/A.pdf';

    if( '2' == $_GET['var'] )
        $url = 'http://example.com/downloads/B.pdf';

    if( '3' == $_GET['var'] )
        $url = 'http://example.com/downloads/C.pdf';

endif;

if( ! empty( $url ) )
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Download</a>';
```